# Twitter API - your application under review

Tags: twitter, twitter-api

подал заявку на регистрацию app на сайте [developer.twitter.com](https://developer.twitter.com/), все бы ничего но до сих пор нет ответа, а твиттер выдает your application under review  и это уже месяц, кто сталкивался с подобным? как быть? подскажите, может я что то неправильно делаю?

Comment: Найдите какие-то другие библиотеки для работы с api, к примеру - https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php

Comment: думаю дело тут не в php

Comment: просто хотел задействовать php